# Change image on JButton on mouse over

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am using an Icon with Java (Swing) `JButton`. Is it possible to change the icon when I take my mouse arrow over it?

I saw somewhere on Youtube that it is possible, but am unable to recall it.

Comment: yes events from ButtonModel can do that, btw are implemented in JButton API too

Comment: `setRolloverIcon()` is the way to go for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of the `JButton` API which provides this kind of support.

Take a look at [`JButton#setRolloverIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverIcon(javax.swing.Icon)) and [`JButton#setRolloverSelectedIcon`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setRolloverSelectedIcon(javax.swing.Icon))

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement `MouseListener` like this:

```
public class YourClass extends JFrame implements MouseListener {    
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) { }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) { }
}
```

Add your function where needed.

Comment: not MouseListener, but ChangeListener & ButtonModel, nethods are implemented in JButton API too

Comment: Please also define how to call an image?
What should I add in {} these brackets?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the mouseEntered() function by implementing a MouseListener and add the code to change the icon in that function.

If you're using an abstract button, you can just use setRolloverIcon() to set an image which will appear on rollOver.